# Any hidden meaning in 'Toddy'?

Tags: meaning-in-context, literature

> I'm a pretty bad fellow myself,' the stranger remarked, 'but Macfarlane is the boy - **Toddy** Macfarlane I call him. Toddy, order your friend another glass.' Or it might be, 'Toddy, you jump up and shut the door.' 'Toddy hates me,' he said again. 'Oh yes, Toddy, you do!'

The extract is taken from the *Body Snatcher* by Robert L. Stevenson.

*Toddy* seems to be just a name, but this word may insinuate another meaning in the above situations.

And Macfarlane is the boy, which means he is 'worse' than the speaker?

Comment: There is "hot toddy", which is an alcoholic drink.

Comment: It sounds like a diminutive for "Todd" or "Robert", noting the author is also Robert.  There is a genre of cocktail called "toddy" so the "order your friend another glass" intro could be more significant.

Comment: I am vaguely recalling that I've read/heard (on British TV shows) "Toddy" used as a nickname of sorts, but one with a seemingly derogatory tone.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found a copy of the short story online here: [readbookonline.net](http://www.readbookonline.net/readOnLine/8454/)

The larger context makes it clear it's just a general-purpose [diminutive](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/diminutive#English) nickname.

(Also, Macfarlane's full name is "Wolfe Macfarlane" )

> One afternoon, when his day's work was over, Fettes dropped into a popular tavern and found Macfarlane sitting with a stranger. This was a small man, very pale and dark, with coal-black eyes. The cut of his features gave a promise of intellect and refinement which was but feebly realised in his manners, for he proved, upon a nearer acquaintance, coarse, vulgar, and stupid. He exercised, however, a very remarkable control over Macfarlane; issued orders like the Great Bashaw; became inflamed at the least discussion or delay, and commented rudely on the servility with which he was obeyed. This most offensive person took a fancy to Fettes on the spot, plied him with drinks, and honoured him with unusual confidences on his past career. If a tenth part of what he confessed were true, he was a very loathsome rogue; and the lad's vanity was tickled by the attention of so experienced a man.
>
> 'I'm a pretty bad fellow myself,' the stranger remarked, 'but Macfarlane is the boy - Toddy Macfarlane I call him. Toddy, order your friend another glass.' Or it might be, 'Toddy, you jump up and shut the door.' 'Toddy hates me,' he said again. 'Oh yes, Toddy, you do!'
>
> 'Don't you call me that confounded name,' growled Macfarlane.